# UIAlertView at the very beginning of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

I have the following at the very beginning of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder:" message:@"foo" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    NSLog(@"%@ is the parent view",[alertView superview]); // prints "(null)"

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    ...
}
```

and the UIAlertView still showed up. How come this works?

Comment: Sorry... What's the theory on why it shouldn't work?

Comment: The theory is that, before self.window = ..., no view has been initialized or displayed. I am guessing that when the UIAlertView is sent the message "show", it is put on a separate thread that waits for everything to be displayed, and then the UIAlertView is displayed. I just wanted to know the exact process or the sequence of events that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert views are shown in their own window. But this doesn't happen until the run loop is given a chance to run. At the time you log the alert view's superview, the alert hasn't been shown yet which is why you get `(null)`.

Comment: So you are saying by the time the run loop is given a chance to run, all the initial views have already been displayed?